# Is it possible to get an attribute value of a widget as declarated in the android layout.xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-resources, android-databinding

Is there a way in an android application to retrieve the attribute value of a widget declared in a `layout.xml`?

for example in my **layout.xml** file i have :

```
<CheckBox
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/clean_filesWithoutVideo"
     android:checked="@{uiprefs.switchButtonEditable}"
     android:id="@+id/checkbox_updateable" />
```

I would like to retrieve the **literal** value for `android:checked`, eg I want to retrieve `"@{uiprefs.switchButtonEditable}"` at runtime.

I searched in `android.content.res.Resources` class using `getResources()` from an Activity without success :

- I cant get the xml file as stream.
- Parsing attributes throught the `Resources.getLayout()` doesn't restitute the attribute value.

Maybe this value is hidden somewhere in the `CheckBox` instance but I can't find it using inspection at debug time...

Note : The value I want to retrive are especially databinding literals. Maybe I could retrieve this through the databinding API ?

Answer (score 1):

Every UI component has it’s own getters and setters through which you can retrieve attributes that are currently set or set what you want to. If the attributes are common among the views, for example height/width, the getter will be available in View class.
In your case, you can get checked attribute through:

```
CheckBox checkbox =  (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_updateable);
boolean initialState = checkbox.isChecked();
```

In Android Studio, you can get the methods available for a particular view. Enter var name (say checkbox) then enter dot (.) and it will show you all available methods. Start typing that you think you are looking for, it will show you all relevant methods.

**UPDATE**

I think [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) is what you are looking for. You can do this :

```
 XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResource);
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

From doc:

> The implementation returned here, unlike using the implementation on
>   top of a generic XmlPullParser, is highly optimized by **retrieving
>   pre-computed information that was generated by aapt when compiling
>   your resources.** For example, the getAttributeFloatValue(int, float)
>   method returns a floating point number previous stored in the compiled
>   resource instead of parsing at runtime the string originally in the
>   XML file.
>
> This interface also provides additional information
>   contained in the compiled XML resource that is not available in a
>   normal XML file, such as getAttributeNameResource(int) which returns
>   the resource identifier associated with a particular XML attribute
>   name.

Comment: Thank you for answering cgr ! But my problem is : I want to get the declarated value (the one i can find in layout.xml) eg : I want to get "@{uiprefs.switchButtonEditable}", not the current state of the CheckBox

Comment: I think I didn't read the question carefully. Sorry for that. At first thought I don't think you'll be able to do that but I'm not sure. I'll try to see if any ways and let you know.

Comment: My bad ! i read again and felt that my question was ambigous. So I edited it to clarifiy a little. Thx for your help !

Comment: @TofferBreeze, I updated answer. If you are still looking for it, try this. This should work.